# Как найти какое приложение выводит часы при отключеном экарне?

Tags: android

Телефон Motorola на Android 6.0, когда выключаешь экран, то он периодически тускленько так выводит часы, но если нажать на Power, то реакция будет такая же как буд-то он просто был заблокирован и экран выключен.
Как найти какое приложение это делает, чтобы посмотреть как оно это делает?
Текущее активи из abd указано - Лаунчер, и это не он.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Motorola этим занимается Motorola Active Display.
Так же есть приложение DynamicNotifications или ActiveNotifications которое можно поставить на любой Android смарт.

Comment: Ничего из вышеперечисленного у меня не обнаружилось :(

Comment: А вы где искали?)

Comment: Пардон! Нашёл, его точное имя com.motolora.motodisplay